# Why are my bathroom outlets and light not working?

Tags: electrical, bathroom, receptacle, light-fixture

First both outlets in my bathroom went out at the same time.  I tried the breaker and it was fine. I reset the outlets, still dead. Now I have one main light in the same bathroom that has 4 different lights on it and only 1 of 4 lights stopped working. All this is in my master bath no other area is affected. On the other side of the wall is my AC unit, not sure if that could have anything to do with it. Any ideas would be great.

Comment: Have you are anyone else recently dona any work in the area, replaced switches, lights?

Comment: Is there a GFCI hiding some place? With 1 of 4 lights that sounds like a coincidence that 1 lamp went out the same time as the GFCI May have tripped.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's somewhere on the supply side in one of the switches.  This is the side that connects to each switch. Search for any "back stab" connections (wires jabbed into a hole which auto-grips the wire, instead of attaching to the side screw).  If you see one, ideally move it to the screw terminals, but only if you can competently a) torque them, and b) know what to do with "2 wires 1 screw" situations.  Otherwise grab the wire firmly, give the wire about a 1/4 turn twist out and back, and see if that brings it back to life.  Do this with the power turned off at the breaker.  If you can't find the breaker, turn off the main breaker and confirm nothing works.

The second place to check is neutral - surely where there is a wire nut full of neutral wires. If there's tape holding the nut on, that's a sure source of trouble - people tend to tape wire-nuts when they have bad technique (or bad nuts) and the nuts won't stay together on their own. Such a flimsy connection is also a bad connection that will do this, or worse!

Also, 2 GFCIs tripping together is a sure sign that somebody didn't understand about downline protection. Move all their wires to the LINE terminals (GFCIs have a way to put 2 wires under 1 screw) and don't use LOAD at all.  It's **only** for downline protection.

If my description revealed some possible knowledge gaps, don't worry, you'll gain it soon enough.